# Calculating distance between coordinates for a car traveling from A to B in real-time by maintaining a temporary constantly updating table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stream table for cars, that will receive pings with coordinates from cars based on their location. Now, I want to create a table from this existing stream table to calculate distance between pings continuously as they come in. 
The input table looks as follows:

[image]

The output table need to maintain one record for each distinct car_id that will maintain the distance traveled by car_id based on the new coordinates. The result table expected looks like this:

[image]

I was able to create a temporary table and views, but not sure how to maintain the output table that gets constantly updated after calculating the distance.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? With Postgres/PostGIS, this should be quite trivial using `st_distance()`

Comment: I am using lsql, which is very similar to sql

Comment: @Coderbunk1992 . . . Do you know how to calculate distance, given latitude and longitude?  You should either include that in the question or make it clear that is what you are really asking about.